# Javascript generators with (a)synchronous functionality

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

So I've been trying to wrap my head around a possible solution but my attempts to stub out a simple example have been unsuccessful.

So I have an array of data that looks something like this:

```
const arr = [{
  "content": "FIRST_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": function callback () {}
},
{
  "content": "SECOND_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": function callback () {}
},
{
  "content": "THIRD_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": function callback () {}
},
{
  "content": "THIRD_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": function callback () {}
}
];
```

I want to create a generator to iterate through that array but not return (yield?) control back to the next iteration until that callback function has been executed.  I tried wrapping that callback in a promise and made it so that the promise wouldn't resolve until that callback was executed.  I tried making sure that the callback was an async function to wrap that promise instead.  I tried a few things but I just wasn't able to get them to work.  After I called the generator function and iterated through it, it just blew through each element of the array.  No matter how I set up the loop, it never waited for the callback to execute before it moved on to the next iteration.

I searched around on but most examples that I found of generators and how they interacted with promises (or async functions), the examples only ever showed something like this `yield Promise.resolve(x)` which isn't what I want.  I don't want it to resolve right away -- I need it to wait until the `callback` is executed.  And the callback would be set up as an onclick handler (to close out a dialog) and would be executed only when that event occurs.  So basically, the next dialog shouldn't instantiate until the previous has been closed.  So for each loop of the array, a few things happen:

- Instantiates a dialog
- Sets up an onclick handler for that dialog.  Ultimately, `callback()` is to be executed somewhere therein.
- I can wrap the callback in a function that returns a Promise (or something along these lines) where the promise doesn't resolve until that event fires.  So when it fires, it both resolves the promise and executes the callback.
- When that happens, the iterator/generator moves on to the next iteration and instantiates the next dialog.  And then the next until the original array has been looped

I'm not saying that my approach is correct.  I could be totally and completely off base.  But there is something niggling in the back of my head that generators and Promises are the way to go.

How would I best implement the functionality I'm trying to achieve?  As I said, I just can't wrap my head around this...

Here's an example of some code that I wrote.  This has gone through several changes as I tried different things.  I'm using fetch() here because I know that it returns a Promise.  I'm convinced that Promises need to feature somewhere in my solution to make sure that my non-async `callback()` is executed before control moves on.  It's fugly but I was just trying different proofs of concept.

```
      async function runRequest(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url);

        return response;
      }

      async function* setupGenerator(arr) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          const response = await runRequest(arr[i]);
          yield response;
        }
      }

      const urls = [
        '/activityViewer/index.html',
        '/message/index.html',
        '/users/index.html',
      ];
debugger;
      const generator = setupGenerator(urls);
      for (let response of generator) {
          console.log('In FOR loop; response; ', response);
      }
```

thnx,
Christoph

Comment: _"looks something like this"_ Can you make sure, it looks invalid - array elements don't have property names.

Comment: do those function return promises or accept callback arguments? because, if not, JavaScript is single threaded so you can't "yield control" until that called function returns or has an implicit return, at which point the function is done and you weren't able to do any other work

Comment: @phuzi, sorry.  You're right.  I updated the structure.

Comment: `After I called the generator function and iterated through it` show that code

Comment: You can't tell if an arbitrary function has been executed, but you can tell if your *wrapped* version of same has. Consider encapsulating these in a trigger function, like `function didRun(fn, hook)` which calls `hook()` then executes `fn()` when called, forwarding all arguments.

Comment: @Samathingamajig, No, they don't return promises but I can wrap them in a Promise().  That's what I was trying to do originally.

Comment: @Christoph wrapping them in a Promise doesn't change anything, you can only yield control due to asynchronous things such as `setTimeout`, `fetch`, `AsyncLocalStorage`, functions that return promises, functions that take callback arguments, etc.

Comment: Your example needs more details showing real examples of what the functions are and what you have actually tried. Don't just say "my attempts to stub out a simple example have been unsuccessful", show your attempts. Edit your question, don't show code in comments!

Comment: It's not clear why your data array contains `callback`s, what these functions do and when they should be called by whom. Please elaborate or add their code.

Comment: @Bergi, as I mentioned in my question, the callback would be used as part of an onclick event handler.  When that event occurs, the callback is executed.  Now, I'm thinking that the event handler actually needs to be a function that wraps the callback.  And it sets up a promise that resolves only when that event actually occurs and the callback() is executed.

Comment: @Christoph Yes, to detect that the event has been fired and the callback was called, you'd need to wrap the callback before setting up the event listener. But that still doesn't answer the question what the callback actually does (is it actually needed? does it contain business logic?), nor where the code is that registers it (or the wrapped function) as a click handler.

Comment: Also it's really unclear why you need an iterator or generator function here. Just put the logic and the waiting in the loop that iterates the array?

Comment: @Bergi, yes, it contains business logic.  It's used to keep track of the fact that a user was presented with the dialog and actually clicked the button/link to close it out.

Comment: @Bergi, that's fair.  I'm not 100% certain that I need a generator.  It just seems like generators are a way to iterate through an array and wait until a particular event (not a dom event kind of event; e.g., Promise.resolve()) occurs before it moves on to the next iteration.  If I can somehow make sure that the promise doesn't resolve until a particular moment in time (e.g, when a button is clicked) then I can make it so that the loop can remain in stasis (waiting for the `yield` or similar) until then.

Comment: You would use *either* callbacks with the business logic *or* a generator function (or actually just an `async` function with some `await`s) with the business logic, but not both

Comment: If you could add some of the business logic (shortened if necessary) code to your question, with pseudocode where you want to wait, I can write up an answer with it

Comment: @Bergi, the callback will execute a `fetch` to an endpoint used to keep track of the fact that a user closed a dialog.  But I want to call that `fetch` only when the click event is triggered.  Which is, _*in part*_, where the Promise angle comes in.  Either the `.then()` calls `Promise.resolve()` from an instantiated promise of we just `await` the `fetch`, I'm not sure.  However, it's still the case that the callback (either itself or a function that wraps it) would only get executed for the onclick event and only then yield control back to the loop to iterate to the next element of the array.

Comment: So, again, X dialogs would be presented for X elements of the array but only *after* a previous dialog was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let the callback be the function that opens the dialog and returns a promise. This promise should resolve when the click handler is called.

Here is an example:

`promiseDialog` is such a callback function: it takes a title to display, and the dialog allows the user to enter some input and close the dialog.

You can have a driver function iterate the array you have given, but each time with `promiseDialog` as callback, and yielding the promise that this callback returns.

Finally, you could consume these yielded promises with a `for await` loop:

(NB: the dialog is not really a *modal* dialog, but it is irrelevant for the demo)

```js
function dialogPromise(title) {
    const dialog = document.querySelector("#dialog");
    dialog.querySelector("p").textContent = title;
    dialog.style.display = "inline-block";
    const button = dialog.querySelector("button");
    const input = dialog.querySelector("input");
    input.value = "";
    input.focus();
    return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
        button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            dialog.style.display = "none";
            // Resolve when paint cycle has happened (to hide dialog)
            requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(() =>
                resolve(input.value)
            ));
        }, { once: true });
    });
}

async function* chainDialogs(tasks) {
    for (const task of tasks) {
        yield task.callback(task.content);
    }
}

(async function() {
    const arr = [
        { "content": "FIRST_CONTENT_HERE",  "callback": dialogPromise }, 
        { "content": "SECOND_CONTENT_HERE", "callback": dialogPromise },
        { "content": "THIRD_CONTENT_HERE",  "callback": dialogPromise },
        { "content": "FOUR_CONTENT_HERE",   "callback": dialogPromise }
    ];
    for await (const result of chainDialogs(arr)) {
        console.log(result);
    }
})();
```

```css
#dialog { position: absolute; display: none; margin: 5vw ; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid; background: #ee8 }
```

```html
<form id="dialog">
    <p>Test dialog</p>
    Your answer: <input>
    <button>OK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you very much.  

Thank you very much for everyone who submitted answers and/or commented.  I learned new things from your comments and I appreciate that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async iterarors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of):

```js
const arr = [{
  "content": "FIRST_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": function callback (_) { return _; }
},
{
  "content": "SECOND_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": function callback (_) { return _; }
},
{
  "content": "THIRD_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": function callback (_) { return Promise.resolve(_); }
},
{
  "content": "FOUR_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": function callback (_) { return _; }
}
];

async function* asyncGenerator(tasks) {
  for (const task of tasks) {
    yield task.callback(task.content);
  }
}

;(async function() {
  for await (const txt of asyncGenerator(arr)) {
    console.log('->', txt);
  }
})();
```

Comment: This is probably the correct answer, but note that with this approach it is the responsibility of the calling code to wait for each Promise to resolve before requesting the next item from the generator.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question, since there are no event listeners nor is the code waiting for anything.

Answer (score 0):

### Generators and Promises have different goals

> *I want to create a generator to iterate through that array but not return (yield?) control back to the next iteration until that callback function has been executed.*

The problem is that generators and Promises have fundamentally different assumptions. A Promise is essentially "I'll work on this 'til I'm done, and call you back when it's finished" while a generator is essentially "Let me know when you are ready for the next one".

If you are using a generator, then you *must* return a value the next time the function is called... you can't wait. So the question is, how important is it to you to wait until the first call is done before beginning the second call?

If you can process all of the callouts at the same time, then your generator can just return Promises and your calling code can take responsibility for `await`ing them.

If, however, it is important that that callouts be processed one at a time in sequence, then you can't use a generator. You can, however, use a callback.

### Solution 1: Maintain control by using a callback argument

This probably isn't *exactly* what you were hoping for, but if you must ensure that the callouts are called one at a time in sequence then this is a simple solution.

```js
const arr = [{
  "content": "FIRST_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": function callback () {}
},
{
  "content": "SECOND_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": function callback () {}
},
{
  "content": "THIRD_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": function callback () {}
},
{
  "content": "THIRD_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": function callback () {}
}
];

async function processList(itemCallback) {
  for (const item of arr) {
    await item.callback();
    itemCallback(item);
  }
}

async function callingCode() {
  await processList(item => {
    // Do something with item...
  });
}
```

### Solution 2: Let the caller have control by returning Promises

If the generator is more about convenience and syntactic beauty than performance or technical requirements, then you can just return Promises and let the calling code handle them:

```js
const arr = [{
  "content": "FIRST_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": async function callback () {}
},
{
  "content": "SECOND_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": async function callback () {}
},
{
  "content": "THIRD_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": async function callback () {}
},
{
  "content": "THIRD_CONTENT_HERE",
  "callback": async function callback () {}
}
];

async function* getList() {
  for (const item of arr) {
    yield item.callback().then(() => item);
  }
}

async function callingCode() {
  for await (const item of getList()) {
    // Do something with item
  }
}
```

Comment: "However, in this case it would be the calling code's responsibility to wait for the Promise to resolve."

Which is kind of what I want because it is the calling code that would be setting up and triggering the dialog to which the callback function would get attached (via an onclick handler)

Comment: Maybe, but your question is a bit confused: "_I want to create a generator to iterate through that array but not return (yield?) control back to the next iteration until that callback function has been executed_". A generator does not have the option of not yielding. It must either yield or else return and finish. So either you must yield a Promise or else you can't use a generator.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address this nuance.

Comment: "So either you must yield a Promise or else you can't use a generator."

Which is why I'm convinced that Promises must feature somewhere in my solution.  I just don't know where or how.  My puzzle pieces haven't been fitting together.

Comment: Yes, Promises feature heavily. So the core question is not "Promises or no", it's "Is there a technical reason to prevent the calling code from triggering all of the callouts at once?" If your code/service can handle all those simultaneous callouts, then just return the Promises and let the calling code sort it out. If not, then don't use a generator.